# If JQuery's .find() faster than .filter()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I'd like to know which way is fastest, as I don't really know how to test the performance myself.

```
<div id="test1">
    <div id="test2">
        <div id="test3">
            <a class="a">asd</a>
            <a class="b">asd</a>
            <a class="c">asd</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For this example I want to get .a and .b

```
$('#test1 #test2 #test3 .a, #test1 #test2 #test3 .b').each(function(){
});
```

OR

```
$('#test1 #test2 #test3 a').find('.a, .b').each(function(){
});
```

OR

```
$('#test1 #test2 #test3 a').filter('.a, .b').each(function(){
});
```

I'm writing a deep path as my real code is much complex and I need to be specific.
What should be fastest?

Comment: You can compare them here, http://jsperf.com/

Comment: Faster still: `[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll("#test3 .a, #test3 .b"),function(elem) { ... });`

Comment: `.find()` and `.filter()` work differently so you cannot compare the two of them for performance. In your example, `.find()` cannot possibly work.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I wonder if `document.getElementById('test3').querySelectorAll('.a,.b')` would be faster still?   Two function calls, but simpler selector parsing.

Comment: @Alnitak [Very much so](http://jsperf.com/jquery-so-selection-nesting/4), in fact. Not sure why I didn't think of that XD

Comment: I win :) http://jsperf.com/jquery-so-selection-nesting/3

Comment: The fastest query is by ID. So no need to have three IDs in your query. The suggested way is to first get the element by ID, and then query inside that element.

Comment: @JuanMendes you've got an extra `#` in your jsperf test case.

Comment: Test cases 4-5 aren't quite the same, though. While I agree that there should be no reason to have to search for nested IDs (since IDs should be unique to begin with), to make it a fair comparison you should probably refactor the other examples so they also only look for the innermost ID.

Comment: @TommyBrunn in my /3 revision there was no measurable difference between `#test1 #test2 #test3` and `#test3` by itself

Comment: That's interesting. I wonder if it's just a matter of ID lookups being very, very fast, or if the browser optimizes the query somehow.

Comment: @TommyBrunn the former, I expect

Answer (score 1):

See for yourself: http://jsperf.com/jquery-so-selection-nesting

Setting up performance tests is quite easy. I suggest you mess around with it yourself. However, make sure that you get the results you expect first. I've edited one of your examples so that it should return the same data (I haven't actually tested it, though).

From the results I'm getting, it looks like using `filter` is even faster than using `querySelectorAll`, when looking at your specific attempts. You should be able to refactor them to be even faster, by not doing excessively long and complicated selectors.

Comment: this is no substantive answer here - benchmarks only tell you the answer for _your_ browser.

Comment: @Alnitak But it's very good indication. Specially with jsperf as other people run the cases in different browsers. I'm not saying that Tommy's case is well written though, his conclusion is misleading since you did show (as I expected) that querying by ID and then querying from that element is fastest (without jQuery)

Comment: @Alnitak: That's true. But it's difficult for me to run benchmarks on all existing browsers. Obviously results may vary depending on the implementation. Especially since the results were fairly close in this case.

Comment: From the results I'm getting, fastest results are obtained by starting the search at the ancestor with the specified ID and not at `document`.  The `.find` method does that, but going to native JS adds another 50% or so performance.